# how to use one form for both user and admin but hidding one input control from the user?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use the same form for both user and admin in laravel 5.8 and I want to hide the upload image Button from the user.

I have tried this code but didn't work:

```
 @if (Str_contains(request()->route()->uri(),'admin'))
            <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                <a class="btn-file">upload_image</a>
                <input type="file" name="image_name" />
            </div>
 @endif
```

these is my route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

    Route::resource('members','MembersController')->except(['create']);



});
```

Users migration:

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use ACL. Check this Laravel doc https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your create_users_table_migration

```
$table->integer('is_admin')->nullable()->default(0); //zero in the db column means the user is not an admin
```

I'm assuming you want to check if the uthenticated user is an admin from your view.blade.php file. If that is the case, you can do something like this

```
@if(auth()->user()->is_admin)
            <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                <a class="btn-file">upload_image</a>
                <input type="file" name="image_name" />
            </div>
 @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
@if(auth()->user()->role == 'admin')
 .. 
  ...
```

or

```
@if(Auth::user()->role/id/name/etc.. == 'admin')
 do something ...
```

Comment: Where do you check if the user is an admin or not

Comment: in the create form >> members/create.blade.php

Comment: Where did you save admin and user?

Comment: views->members/create * for admin *
        views->guest   * all userfiles are in this folder *

Comment: If I understood you, you should make one form called `create.blade.php`, and in your controller return `User::all`. then in view, you could check if the user is admin or not. `@if($user->name == 'John Doe')`

Comment: Bro. In this type of website . the guest can't register or create an account its like  News website. the admin gets control of everything.